# Month Week and Day View for Calendar in appcelerator

Tags: calendar, widget, appcelerator

I am new to appcelerator.Do we have a widget for Calendar which can implement Month week and Day View.I was searching through some widgets http://gitt.io/ but couldn't find one.Can some one help me with this?

My specifications are :Application Type:Mobile titanium SDK:4.0.GA Platform & Version :iOS 8 xcode :6 Host os IOS,target device :iPad